# obfuscate password in qt

Tags: qt, encryption, passwords

I want to store a password (no hash) on my disk. it's nothing sensitive but i just don't want it in plaintext on my disk.
what i tried till now is:
converting the string in binary and XOR it with the binary of a key.

```
bool ok = true;

QByteArray qbaPW("mypass");

long long intPW = qbaPW.toHex().toLongLong( &ok, 16 );

QString binPW = QString::number( intPW, 2);
```

but the thing is, that it only works with short passwords. if they are too long intPW gets too big for longlong. any ideas how can avoid that thing?

cheers

Comment: Don't use a `long long`, stick to `QByteArray` and cycle through till the end.

Comment: If it's nothing too sensitive and you don't mind a particularly savvy person cracking your system, you could just use the standard `QByteArray::toBase64()`

Comment: could you give me a hint how i get the binary of the word in a QByteArray, please? I'm stuck :-/

Comment: another solution: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq12-iodevice.html

Answer (score 0):

A `QByteArray` is like a `char array[len]` in C. You can access individual members and do whatever you please with them. For example:

```
QByteArray const key("mykey");
QByteArray password("password");

for (int ik = 0, ip = 0; 
     ip < password.length(); 
     ++ ip, ik = (ik+1 < key.length() ? ik+1 : 0)) {
  password[ip] = password[ip] ^ key[ik];
}
```

Since this just XORs with the key, you repeat this procedure to decrypt the password. A good key will be generated randomly and will be longer than the longest password you envisage (say 64 characters).

Do note that this method is only reasonably safe if the users are **explicitly informed not to reuse any other password in your application** - otherwise you're essentially leaking passwords that are supposed to be secure.